# WinSSHD, GIT over SSH Team City Fetch Url - Does not appear to be a git repo

Tags: windows, ssh, git, teamcity

We used to work with windows network paths to connect to git, but starting to use team city we want to use SSH.

I'm having trouble testing a connection to a git repo on a server here at 192.168.X.XXX in the local network over SSH:
This server has a secondary disk **D:** containing the Git central/bare repositories at

> D:\Git\MyProjectName.git\

The ssh user has an Initial terminal shell directory of

> D:\Git

This is set up as Fetch-Url in team-city:

> ssh://ourgitusername@192.168.X.XXX:22/MyProjectName.git

We installed bitvise WinSSHD as the ssh server, and I'm able to connect to it using putty, and I can browse that folder ,the git repo IS a bare repository, yet I'm getting the error

> List remote refs failed:
>   org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException:
>   ssh://ourgitusername@192.168.X.XXX/MyProjectName.git: fatal:
>   ''/MyProjectName.git'' does not appear to be a git repository

I tried changing the home directory, and Have tried about 10 different styles of writing that path, it still won't work...!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using '\' instead of '/' after the IP?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work either